# Change .html URL depending on the active div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, redirect

I have two html pages: index1.html and index2.html. In index1.html, I have two buttons: Get Started and Login. In index2.html, I have two divs (Sign-up form and Sign-in form), and either one of them is active (by setting them with active class). The default active is the sign-up form: `<div class="form sign-up-form active">...</form>`, and the other form, which is for signing-in is not yet set as active: `<div class="form sign-in-form">...</div>`

Note that index2.html is a double slider page, where it does not scroll down, as the divs are positioned beside each other.

I want my Get Started button from index1.html to redirect to index2.html, but on the active Sign-up form, and I want my Login button from index1.html to redirect to index2.html, but on the active Sign-in form.

The problem is I can't redirect them on a specific active div. The URL of index2.html only goes with "index2.html?#". How do I change the URL depending on the active div? ex. index2.html#sign-up if the Sign-up form is active and index2.html?#sign-in if the Sign-in form is active.

Comment: RE: [your deleted PDF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784605/view-file-from-upload-file-button-in-html) People can still find closed questions and read the comments. 
A closed question can be reopened when the community find the question is detailed enough to re-open. You deleted the question and now only high-rep people can see it. Add more information and effort and undelete it  - so I can re-open it

Answer (score 0):

In index1.html you can use hashtag in your href

```
<a href="index2.html#sign-in"><div>Sign in</div></a>
```

In index2.html you can check if there is sign-in hashtag in the url

```
const signInForm = document.getElementById("sign-in-form")
const currentHash = window.location.hash
if(currentHash.includes('sign-in')){
    signInForm.classList.add("active")
    signUpForm.classList.remove("active")
}
```

(Note that i put id in your sign in and sign up button)

```
<div id="sign-up-form" class="form sign-up-form active">Sign Up</div>
<div id="sign-in-form" class="form sign-in-form">Sign in</div>
```

For explanation, the location.hash property sets or returns the anchor part of a URL, including the hash sign (#). And then after we get the hashtag from the url, we can check if there is 'sign-in' word in our hashtag

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to simulate and implement a solution on it, Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uawtkc?file=login.html, hope it helps.

Basically, you would require a bit of JS to mark active on when which element you want to target to activate when navigating from one file to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url to follow your element classes, you have to get the elements first, and then get their classes, and then check which one have active classes

```
<div id="sign-up-form" class="form sign-up-form active">Sign Up</div>
<div id="sign-in-form" class="form sign-in-form">Sign in</div>
```

Get their classes

```
const signInForm = document.getElementById("sign-in-form").classList
const signUpForm = document.getElementById("sign-up-form").classList
```

Check which one is active

```
if (signInForm.contains("active")) window.location.hash = "SignIn"
if (signUpForm.contains("active")) window.location.hash = "SignUp"
```

You can change the url hashtag with this window.location.hash = "new word"